# Button id returns blank?

Tags: javascript, button, meteor

```
<template name="thingform">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <!-- Project Name Form-->
        <form class="col s6">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
                <input placeholder="{{projectDoc}}" name="tname" type="text" class="validate">
                <label>Thing Name</label>
            </div>

            <button id="yoid" class="btn waves-effect waves-light tbutton" type="submit">
                <i class="material-icons right">Submit</i>
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Template is this and the JavaScript is

```
Template.thingform.helpers({
projectDoc: function() {
    return "Hello";
}
});

Template.thingform.events({
"click .tbutton": function(e) {
    var bid = e.target.id;
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(bid);
}
});
```

Why does the console show up blank? Shouldn't it print "yoid" which is the id on the button?

I've also tried using jQuery

```
var bid = $(e.target).prop("id");

var bid = $(e.target).attr("id");
```

Also tried this

```
var bid = event.currentTarget.id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried your exact code:

```
<!-- Project Name Form-->
<form class="col s6">
  <div class="input-field col s6">
      <input placeholder="{{projectDoc}}" name="tname" type="text" class="validate">
      <label>Thing Name</label>
  </div>

  <button id="yoid" class="btn waves-effect waves-light tbutton" type="submit">
      <i class="material-icons right">Submit</i>
  </button>
</form>

"click .tbutton": function(e) {
  var bid = e.currentTarget.id;
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(bid); // Logs 'yoid'
}
```

I think you have a typo: you said you tried `event.currentTarget.id` whereas I have `e.currentTarget.id`.  `e.target` gives you the inner contents of the button, so you want currentTarget.